# Where are regular functions stored (or displayed) on Google cloud / Firebase?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I deployed a regular function on Google Firebase including some shared functionality for my other cloud functions.

By regular I mean something like:

```
function foo() {
...
}
```

Where can I find these functions listed? Google Cloud console search returns nothing.
I can see all my other deployed cloud functions like Https callables, Auth triggers, etc.

I can call the function just fine from inside other cloud functions so it must be somewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cloud Functions only keeps a list of the **Cloud Functions** in your project, as it needs to trigger those. It does not keep a track of other artifacts in your code base, such as these regular JavaScript functions. Your own code can indeed call these functions as it normally would, but Cloud Functions doesn't have to do anything with them - so it doesn't track them.

Since this is a regular JavaScript function, and not a Cloud Function, it is not listed anywhere in the Firebase or Google Cloud console. The code is just present in the `index.js` file or other file where you placed it.

Comment: Ok that makes some sense but where would I find this file online? I deployed this function with the firebase deploy command. Am I doing this wrong?

Comment: Why do you need to find the file online? I mean, it does exist of course - but what's your goal here (also see: what is th [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)).

Comment: My goal is to know where to find my files, how to edit them and how to delete them if I need to.  
Moreover, it feels weird to have no idea what function and what version is deployed unless I keep separate logs about this. Right now the only reason I know this function is online is because I still remember.

Comment: It sounds like you're asking [how to get/see the current code in Google Cloud Functions](https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+get%2Fsee+the+current+code+in+Google+Cloud+Functions). That allows you to find the code from which the current container was built.

Comment: I had already tried looking there but the confusion arose from the fact that only cloud functions are listed. Turns out that the "source" tab of each function leads to my index.js file including all the regular functions (and everything else in fact).
I falsely assumed this would lead to each respective function's code only.
Btw you said "it is not listed anywhere in the Firebase or Google Cloud console" but it turns out it's right there on Google cloud console after all... maybe I wasn't clear enough, but all good in the end.

Thanks for the help Frank, I appreciate it!